# Python - invalid syntax in conditions

Tags: python, tkinter, conditional-statements

I am studying how to use conditions in Python and I have no idea why on earth there's a syntax error in my code, when I have just written normal condition:
`else y>200:`

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from random import *
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(0, 200, 400, 200)

def utvar(suradnice):
    x=suradnice.x
    y=suradnice.y
    if y<200: 
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+30, y+30, fill='blue')
    else y>200: #invalid syntax error is there between else and y
        canvas.create_oval(x-15, y-15, x+15, y+15, fill='yellow')

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', utvar)
```

Comment: I think you just mean `else:`. Else is run if the preceding if-condition was false, so `y` is greater than or equal to 200. You don't need to put another condition on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
else y>200:
```

should be

```
elif y>200:
```

You can look into the documentation for `if` statements: [`if` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)